# Laravel 7 419 Page Expired in POST methods

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-7

I've upload a Laravel 7 project on `cpanel`. All `post` methods give a `419 - page expired` error, but it works fine in `localhost`.

I've set all `@csrf`s exactly on the forms. I've set session domain in `env` file. But it still doesn't work.

Instead, it returns:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53
```

Comment: Cpanel also have problems sometimes with this . Try doing php artisan cache:clear locally and upload it again

Comment: Before upload your laravel project on cPanel, clear your cache, config, route & view

Comment: ^ I would love to know what cache has to do with csrf token ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with migrating website from http to https

Comment: This method worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Do you have CSRF in your header?

```
<!-- CSRF token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add in your form on .blade.php file {{ csrf_field() }} or @csrf like this**

```
<form method='POST' action='route("exampleRoute")'>
   {{ csrf_field() }} or @csrf

      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">STitle</label>
            <input type="text" name='title' class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="">
      </div>
   ....
   ....
</form>
```